# show popup or lightbox after x pages visited on my website

Tags: jquery, session, cookies, popup

I'm trying to find a solution to display a pop, lightbox or div (doesn't matter for a moment), after any visitors has visited 3 pages of my website. and only once by session.

I've found infos about jquery.cookies and I guess this might be a good solution, just wanted to know if someone here knows a way of doing it.

I'd like to use a jquery code. I know how to display and hide... but I don't know who to do my if statement, getting the cookie values.

any ideas ?

thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, I thought it will be usefull to share it with you.

first you have to use jquery.cookies plugin.

and then here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // create cookie
    var visited = $.cookie('visited'); // visited = 0
     visited++; // increase counter of visits
        $.cookie('visited', visited, {
            path:'/', //Path all my website pages
        });   

    if (visited == 3) {
        // DO THIS
        alert("popup");
    } else {

     }
});
```

thanks